# FoxPro - What is incorrect about this SCAN FOR loop?

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I get an error: 'command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword' when I try to run a Scan For loop that looks like:

```
SCAN FOR table2_data.item_id = table1_data.item_id AND table2_data.status LIKE '%loaded%'
```

Any thoughts on why this is incorrect?

For some reason it works with:

```
SCAN FOR table2_data.item_id = table1_data.item_id AND table2_data.status = ALLTRIM('loaded')
```

Can I not use LIKE in a SCAN FOR loop?

Comment: In FoxPro `Like` is an `SQL` operator but not an `xBase` command, see also the `Like()` function. You can press the F1 key to open the Help file inside the IDE

Comment: As Stefan said, LIKE doesn't exist in xBase. It is an SQL clause. You can simply use your second variation (as I already know, you are using LIKE '%loaded%' because of leading and trailing spaces).

Comment: Second one is the way to go except for a small correction: SCAN FOR table2_data.item_id = table1_data.item_id AND alltrim(table2_data.status) = 'loaded'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code is the way to go, except for a small correction:

```
SCAN FOR table2_data.item_id = table1_data.item_id AND alltrim(table2_data.status) = 'loaded'
```

You can also take casing into account and write that as:

```
SCAN FOR table2_data.item_id = table1_data.item_id AND lower(alltrim(table2_data.status)) = 'loaded'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SCAN FOR table2_data.item_id = table1_data.item_id AND LIKE('*loaded*',table2_data.status)
```

I don't remember using LIKE() function; I used to use the "$" operator which works like like!